# Ubuntu 21.04 will not boot - help

Tags: boot, system-installation, asus

New installation of Ubuntu 21.04
I have installed 3x times, but when it comes to boot from drive, it shuts down after these messages:

```
[    0.235786] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS  
[    0.763790] igc 0000:6e:00.0: no suspend buffer for PTM  
[   83.121442] thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0 failed to send driver ready to ICM  
/dev/nvme1n1p2: recovering journal  
/dev/nvme1n1p2: clean, 181888/31227904 files, 4327718/124895488 blocks
```

First message fixed by enabling VM in BIOS.
I started on a 3820x1600 monitor, but moved to HD TV - using HDMI.
I don't know what to do about the other messages.
Tried 20.04 - would not go to graphic mode to install from usb - power restart.
Tried Fedora - When it would go to graphics mode to install - power restart.
Any help appreciated.

Hardware (all new):

- ASUS ROG STRIX Z590-I gaming series
- Intel i7-11700 + Fan
- Corsair Vengeance DDR4 3200
- Samsung M.2 980 Pro
- IN WIN case
- Flashed BIOS with latest from asus

Comment: Are you trying to install in a virtual machine?

Comment: No. I don't know why VMX was required with the install.

Comment: I reset BIOS - and tried again -same. Contacting ASUS to get some ideas.

Comment: Seems there is very little chance that a build-your-own PC will be supported by any version of linux.